# Meaning of "unqualified" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> I. She goes to school.
>   II. She may/must go to school
>
> As a main clause, [I] is a characteristically used as an ***unqualified*** assertion. She may go, by contrast, indicates that the situation possibly obtains or is permitted, while […].
>
> (*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*)

What does *unqualified* mean?

Comment: This is *qualify* in the sense of "limit". An "unqualified" assertion is one with no limits on it: something is stated to be entirely true, with no exceptions or conditions.

Comment: @StoneyB That is the correct answer, might as well make it an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Qualify" originally meant “cause (something) to have a particular quality” or “attribute a particular quality to (something)”. Over the centuries the sense has broadened to mean, among other things, to “(cause to) acquire the particular qualities necessary” for something or to do something, and that is the sense in which you will usually encounter the passive participle: typically, some is or is not *qualified* for a particular job.

In this case, however, it is the original meaning which is employed. An *unqualified assertion* is one to which no limiting quality has been attributed: “This is a fact—not *possibly* a fact or a *particular kind* of fact or a fact *under such-and-such circumstances*, but simply a fact.”

Answer (score 0):

In supplement to user 'StoneyB' 's sterling answer, I thought to add 
[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=qualify&allowed_in_frame=0.)'s etymology

> ...Meaning "to limit, modify" is from 1530s. Sense of "be fit for a job" first appeared 1580s. ....

and [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unqualified), but beware that here, only definition 2 matches the context and is apt:

> 2. Without reservation or limitation; total:

For an example involving 'references', consult also https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/38750.